# VM DNS ISSUE with Host machine but not VM client

Tags: virtual-machine, dns

I am running Oracle VirtualBox VM. DNS works Fine on the host machine but once i start up a VM the Host losses ability to communicate with the DNS.The VM meanwhile has no connection issues. I have tried uninstalling both the NIC and VM and nothing seems to help. Tracert shows that all traffic is being routed back the the host ip. Any help would be appreciated. VM is in bridged mode. When it is in NAT the issue clears up.

Comment: does your VM have a DHCP server running?

Comment: yes. DHCP is enabled on both the host and the VM

Comment: No, does the VM have a DHCP **server** running?  Is it hijacking your host's DHCP lease?

Comment: oh..no it is not running a DHCP server.